# Query em Laravel

Tags: laravel, query

Olá, Estou com um pequeno problema na query em laravel.

Tenho a seguinte query

```
    $ferias = feria::where('id_funcionario', '=', $userid)
    ->get('n_ferias_disponiveis');
```

O que quero é :

Select 'n_ferias_disponiveis' where id_funcionario', '=', $userid

Onde estou a errar?

Answer (score -2):

Você pode tentar dessa forma:

```
#ferias = feria::select('n_ferias_disponiveis1)
                ->where('id_funcionario', $userid)
                ->get();
```

Obs: e sempre verifique se a sintaxe dos dados está correta, nome da model, coluna do banco no where, etc...

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).